# bootstrap not working in ruby on rails: navbar not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am trying to load the gem from bootstrap and display a navbar on my page but it doesn't seem to work.

gemfile code

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'


group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

application.css.scss

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Etsydemo</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= render 'shared/navbar' %>
<div class= "container">
<%= yield %>

<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

_navbar.html.erb

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

Toggle navigation
        
        
        
      
      Etsydemo

```
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/pages/Contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pages/about">About</a></li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't describe the problem.  What doesn't work?  Is there an error?  Did you check the compiled results?

Comment: sorry for being vague. I am a complete beginner. I want the navbar to be up top. instead the navbar appears to be not loaded(not sure about the terminology). there is a button that says toggle navigation. but it doesnt work. If i try to use bootstrap css components like 'button', nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Did you look at the compiled CSS?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure what you mean by compiled css. I am a novice. I deeply appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reorganizing your application.js (assuming you have the bootstrap.js loaded into the asset pipeline...if you have the minified version it would be bootstrap.min)

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to import bootstrap sprockets as well as bootstrap. So the top of your application.scss file should have:

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ollie. I figured it out eventually. It works.

Comment: I have the same issue, but if I try this I get the error `File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets`. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you got `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` in your gemfile, and have you run `bundle install`?